# python schedule not working for specific time

Tags: python, python-schedule

I am using the python [schedule](https://pypi.org/project/schedule/) module. I have a function that I am trying to run at a specfic time. When I try to run it on my local machine it runs at the specified time, however on an ubuntu server it doesn't. When I try to run the task every 5 seconds it works on an ubuntu server so I'm confused on the problem.

Just to note. When I tried testing this an an ubuntu server I changed the time to a couple of minutes ahead of the current time and then started the bot, I'm not sure if this could be the problem.

```
import schedule
import time    

def job():
    print('hello')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    schedule.every(10).seconds.do(job) // this works
    schedule.every().day.at("08:00").do(job)

while 1:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Probably easier to install a cron job imo. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-cron-to-automate-tasks-ubuntu-1804

Comment: I guess the server time is not the same as your local machine

Comment: Ah that's probably the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Stradivari said, the problem was that the server time wasn't the same as my local machine time.

I fixed it by following this guide: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-time-synchronization-on-ubuntu-18-04